# set ordered dict inside a ordinary dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have a normal dictionary d1 and ordered dictionary d2. 
This is possible to set nested ordinary dictionary but How can I set d2 inside d1.

```
d1 = {'a' : 'aa'}
d2 = OrderedDict([('b', 'bb') , ('c', 'cc')]}
```

Comment: Can't you just use the `update` method in the dictionary ? `d1.update(d2)`

Answer (score 0):

By giving it a key:

```
d1['d2'] = d2
```

Gives you:

```
{'a': 'aa', 'd2': OrderedDict([('b', 'bb'), ('c', 'cc')])}
```

Also, your second line is wrong

```
d2 = OrderedDict([('b', 'bb') , ('c', 'cc')])
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `update()` method:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d1 = {'a' : 'aa'}
d2 = OrderedDict([('b', 'bb') , ('c', 'cc')])

d1.update(d2)
print(d1)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'c': 'cc'}
```